# Django nested for loops: Is it possible to use the result from the first loop within the definition of the second for loop?

Tags: python, django, templates

In my Django template I am trying to create a for loop within a for loop. I am trying to use the result of one of the fields as the name for the list in the second for constructor.

I have two objects successfully passed to my template:

```
sectList = {"Id": 1, "Section": "Home", "Identifier": "homeList"}

homeList = {"Id": 1, "Title": "Home", "Url": "home/",
            "Id": 2, "Title": "My Account", "Url": "account/",
            "Id": 3, "Title": "Full List", "Url": "fullList/",}
```

In my template I have:

```
  <ul>
    {% for section in sectList %}
      {% autoescape off %}
        <li class="middle_table_li">
          <table class="middle_table">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="middle_table_cell">
                <a href="" class="middle_a_dark">
                  {{ section.Identifier }}
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              {% for view in section.Identifier %}
                <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
                  {{ view.title }}
                  <table style="text-align: left;">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="{{ view.url }}" class="left_a_light">{{ view.title }}</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
          </table>
        </li>
      {% endautoescape %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

When I use "***{% for view in section.Identifier %}***", *view.title* returns the word "homeList", split one character per iteration (h, o, m, e, etc.). When I try "***{% for view in {{section.Identifier}} %}***" it gives me the below error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Could not parse the remainder: '{{section.Identifier}}' from '{{section.Identifier}}'
```

My question is how can I use the results form one queryset within the constructor of a for loop? In the template, section.Identifier = 'homeList', and the view successfully sends the homeList data over, but instead of using the homeList variable from the view, it appears to split the string into a list, like list("homeList"), and the result is that each row consists of a single character from the word *homeList*. In regular python code I could use something like exec to execute the string as code, but I am unsure of how to do this in a django template, if it is even possible at all?

**EDIT #1 (FYI, all data is passed successfully to the template)**

***views.py***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import connection, transaction
from app_HomeView.models     import HomeList
from view_LeftPanel.models   import LeftPanelList

def HomeView(request):
    homeList = HomeList.objects.all().order_by("title")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM view_leftpanelview_sectionlist ORDER BY Id;")
    desc = cursor.description
    sectList = [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    return render(request, "index.html", {"homeList": homeList,
                                          "sectList": sectList,})
```

Comment: Could you please show the code of your view?

Comment: @alecxe: Thanks for your quick response, please see Edit #1 for views.py code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can, but your view code passed the wrong value, that's why it didn't work. You have:

```
sectList = [{"Id": 1, "Section": "Home", "Identifier": "homeList"}]
```

Then in the template, after the first loop, the result of `section.Identifier` is obviously `"homeList"`, so it's like you run:

```
for i in "homeList":
    print i
```

it would print out every character of "homeList" string.

So what you need to do is to nest the list of `homeList` inside the `secList`, your `secList` should be something like this:

```
sectList = [{ 
    "Id": 1, "Section": "Home", "Identifier": [  # Identifier should be a list
        {"Id": 1, "Title": "Home", "Url": "home/"},
        {"Id": 2, "Title": "About", "Url": "about/"}
    ] 
}]
```

And this is your challenge, right?

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed the mistake in my question, the sectList/homeList were already inside a list. Using your approach I was able to find a solution, I will try to post the code a bit later

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the collection should look more like

```
sectList = {"Id": 1, "Section": "Home",
"Identifier": {"Id": 1, "Title": "Home", 
"Url": "home/","Id": 2, "Title": "My Account",
 "Url": "account/","Id": 3, "Title": "Full List",
 "Url": "fullList/",}}
```

You see - "Identifier": "homeList" is not really a link to your second list. Its just a prop. name and value.